# Incorrect behavior of switch statement in while loop in C#

Tags: c#, switch-statement, do-while

I have a problem with my code. Mostly I have no problems with the switch statement combined with the do-while loop. I think the problem lies in the ConsoleKey function, but since I start my adventure with programming, I can't solve the problem. So I hope someone from this great community will help me. If it's possible I want to use press key to choose an option in switch statement. Thanks for help. P.S. English is not my first language, so if I misspelled anything, sorry.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Attention");
            Console.WriteLine("Choose 1-2");
            var inputData = Console.ReadKey();
            do
            {

               switch (inputData.Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.X:
                        Console.WriteLine("action 1");
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.Y:
                        Console.WriteLine("action 2");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Default");
                        break;
                }
            } while (inputData.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Why the Console.ReadKey is outside the loop?

Comment: Which one? At the bottom, it's for end program. But this with var inputData, I think that is right place for that. But I am not 100% convinced.

Comment: So what happens? You press a key and the program goes crazy printing the same message over and over again?

Comment: Yup, this is what is happening.

Comment: So you ask for a key before entering the loop, then you start a loop hoping that the key typed at the start changes in some way into the Escape key to allow you to exit the loop? Probably a little of [rubber duck debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) would have helped

Comment: Thank you, the rubber duck debugging cleared my mind a little. I'm still learning to understand the code correctly. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            Console.WriteLine("Attention");
            Console.WriteLine("Choose 1-2");
            ConsoleKeyInfo inputData = Console.ReadKey();
            do
            {

                switch (inputData.Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.X:
                        Console.WriteLine("action 1");
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.Y:
                        Console.WriteLine("action 2");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Default");
                        break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Choose 1-2");
                inputData = Console.ReadKey();
            } while (inputData.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: So my mistake was that in the loop it was not possible to change the value of the variable again?